# Using the time functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a small question. I have an array that saves dates in the following format.

```
'01/02/20|07/02/20'
```

It is saved as a string, which uses the start date on the left side of the "|" and end date on the other side.

It is only the end date that matters here, but is there a function or algorithm I can use to automatically calculate the difference in days and months between now.datetime and the end date (right-hand side of "|")?

Thanks, everyone

Comment: So, split the string and convert the second half to a `datetime` object.

Comment: Assuming the data is stored in variable `x`, then you can use `x.split('|')[1]` to get the end data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this.

Python `datetime` module is the way to go for a problem like this

```py
import datetime

dates = '01/02/20|07/02/20'

enddate = dates.split('|')[-1]
# Use %y for 2 digits year else %Y for 4 digit year
enddate = datetime.datetime.strptime(enddate, "%d/%m/%y") 

today = datetime.date.today()
print(abs(enddate.date() - today).days)
```

Output:

```sh
81
```

Comment: It is not necessary to make sure that the year has 4 digits. `%y` is the [format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) to use in this case.

Comment: @Brayoni, thanks for the tip. I've modified my answer now

Answer (score 2):

[datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) is the main routine for parsing strings into datetimes. It can handle all sorts of formats, with the format determined by a format string you give it:

```
In [34]: from datetime import datetime

In [35]: end_date = datetime.strptime(s.split('|')[1], '%d/%m/%y')

In [36]: diff = datetime.now() - end_date

In [37]: diff
Out[37]: datetime.timedelta(days=81, seconds=81712, microseconds=14069)

In [38]: diff.days
Out[38]: 81
```